# when spring-rabbit dependency added to pom.xml mvn is giving exceptions

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

This is the code which I had added to my spring project which is not getting started when trying to run with tomcat.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What are the exceptions?

Comment: This is the first exception generated when mvn tomcat is run: nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory

Comment: Find that JAR and add that dependency.  Keep going until all the exceptions are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Instead of two dependencies add only one dependency as follows.

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```